# Javascript select and sum column contents

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have implemented the WP_List_Table extension, which renders to a HTML table:

```
<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped table-view-list items">
  <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:item">
    <tr bgcolor="#b2dfbc">
      <th scope="row" class="check-column">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="34">
      </th>
      <td class="title column-title has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Order">#34 customer name1
        <span style="color:silver">(id:34)</span>
        <div class="row-actions">
          <span class="edit"><a href="admin.php?page=wc-orders&amp;action=edit&amp;id=34">Edit</a>
          </span>
        </div><button type="button" class="toggle-row">
      </td>
      <td class="date_created column-date_created" data-colname="Date created">February 6, 2024
      </td>
      <td class="items column-items" data-colname="Items">Shirt - Green, Shoes
      </td>
      <td class="total column-total" data-colname="Total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
          <bdi>38,00&nbsp
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€
            </span>
          </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="status column-status" data-colname="Status">submitted
      </td>
      <td class="processid column-processid" data-colname="Cotton Process ID">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#b2dfbc">
      <th scope="row" class="check-column"><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="35">
      </th>
      <td class="title column-title has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Order">#35 customer name2
        <span style="color:silver">(id:35)
        </span>
        <div class="row-actions">
          <span class="edit"><a href="admin.php?page=wc-orders&amp;action=edit&amp;id=35">Edit</a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="date_created column-date_created" data-colname="Date created">February 6, 2024
      </td>
      <td class="items column-items" data-colname="Items">Jacket, Shirt - Cream
      </td>
      <td class="total column-total" data-colname="Total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
          <bdi>50,00&nbsp;
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€
            </span>
          </bdi>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="status column-status" data-colname="Status">submitted
      </td>
      <td class="processid column-processid" data-colname="Cotton Process ID">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In each row there is a price row for example:

```
<td class="total column-total" data-colname="Total">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi>38,00&nbsp
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€
      </span>
    </bdi>
  </span>
</td>
```

Also each row has a checkbox. I want to write a javascript code, that captures which checkbox has been checked and then I want to sum the amount provided in the checked rows. I was able to write javascript code that captures which row has been selected and returns the ID of the selected row for example #34 or #35. Here is a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    let enabledSettings = []
    
    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            enabledSettings = 
            Array.from(checkboxes)
            .filter(i => i.checked)
            .map(i => i.value)
        console.log(enabledSettings)
        })
    });
</script>
```

I need now to extract the amount provided on the specific selected rows and then sum it. Can you provide how to further modify the code?

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. I would retrieve the amount from the closest table row to the checkbox and put them into an array to sum. Or start at zero and just sum without the array.

Comment: I do not require code writing services as most of the code is already implemented. I just need a few tips on how to proceed further. To rephrase my question: given the 'value' fields of the selected checkboxes returned by my JavaScript code, how can I retrieve the contents of the specific column associated with the row of the selected checkbox?  I apologize if my question is bothersome to you.

Comment: I would look into [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  let enabledSettings = []

  checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      console.log(parseFloat(checkbox.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.amount').querySelector('bdi').innerText));
      enabledSettings =
              Array.from(checkboxes)
                      .filter(i => i.checked)
                      .map(i => i)
      console.log(enabledSettings)
      var sum=0;
      for (let i = 0; i < enabledSettings.length; i++ ) {
   sum += parseFloat(enabledSettings[i].parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.amount').querySelector('bdi').innerText);
      }

      console.log(sum) // 15
    })
  });
</script>
```